# replace values from a column into another if it contains 2 substrings

Tags: pandas

I have a df like this:

```
            xx    yy
AAsdsd_ss   3     2
AAassa_ss   3     1
CC          4     7 
DD          7     6
```

I would like that if the index str.contain AA and _ss to substitute the values of column yy into xx to generate the following output:

```
            xx    
AAsdsd_ss   2     
AAassa_ss   1         
CC          4      
DD          7
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[df.index.to_series().str.match('^AA.*_ss$'), 'xx'] = df['yy']
```

Output:

```
           xx  yy
AAsdsd_ss   2   2
AAassa_ss   1   1
CC          4   7
DD          7   6
```

**Note**: the code matches `AA` at beginning and `_ss` at the end. If you simply want them anywhere, in any order:

```
s = df.index.to_series()
df.loc[s.str.contains('AA') & s.str.contains('_ss'), 'xx'] = df['yy']
```